# What is the size of int on a 8-bit processor?

Tags: integer, size, 8-bit

I was asked in an interview, what is the size of integer on a 8-bit processor machine?
I answer 8 bits. Is it right?

Comment: From the perspective of what?

Comment: Processor bitness and int size are unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

The RANGE of an 8 bit INTEGER is;

-128 to 127 and has 1 byte per element.

Answer (score 0):

Integer is a higher-level programming concept not strictly tied to the size of the memory positions in a processor or the number of bytes the processor can operate on in a single operation (word size). 64-bit integers existed before the 64-bit processor. In an 8 bit processor a 64-bit integer would just be stored in multiple memory positions (this will however mean a lot more work for a < 64-bit processor to process - since it would have to do reads/writes and calculations involving multiple memory positions).